# Counting all nested objects in array where selected attribute is true

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to create a recursive function counting objects nested in the array where the `selected` attribute is `true`.

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"code":"1","selected":false,"children":[{"id":4,"code":"1.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":5,"code":"1.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":6,"code":"1.01.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":20,"code":"1.01.003","selected":true,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":2,"code":"2","selected":false,"children":[{"id":7,"code":"2.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":9,"code":"2.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":21,"code":"2.01.002","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":22,"code":"2.01.003","selected":false,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":3,"code":"3","selected":false,"children":[{"id":8,"code":"3.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":10,"code":"3.01.01","name":"Sementes","selected":false,"children":[{"id":11,"code":"3.01.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":23,"code":"3.01.01.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":24,"code":"3.01.01.003","selected":true,"children":[]}]},{"id":25,"code":"3.01.02","selected":false,"children":[{"id":27,"code":"3.01.02.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":28,"code":"3.01.02.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":29,"code":"3.01.02.003","selected":false,"children":[]}]},{"id":26,"code":"3.01.03","selected":false,"children":[{"id":30,"code":"3.01.03.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":31,"code":"3.01.03.002","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":32,"code":"3.01.03.003","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":35,"code":"3.01.03.004","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":34,"code":"3.01.03.005","selected":false,"children":[]}]}]}]}];


const countSelectedChildren = (arr) => {

return arr;
}

console.log(countSelectedChildren(data))
```

**Expected response:**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "code": "3",
    "selected": false,
    "selectedChildren": 6,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "code": "3.01",
        "selected": false,
        "selectedChildren": 6,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "code": "3.01.01",
            "name": "Sementes",
            "selected": false,
            "selectedChildren": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 11,
                "code": "3.01.01.001",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 23,
                "code": "3.01.01.002",
                "selected": false,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 24,
                "code": "3.01.01.003",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 25,
            "code": "3.01.02",
            "selected": false,
            "selectedChildren": 1,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 27,
                "code": "3.01.02.001",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 28,
                "code": "3.01.02.002",
                "selected": false,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 29,
                "code": "3.01.02.003",
                "selected": false,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 26,
            "code": "3.01.03",
            "selected": false,
            "selectedChildren": 3,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 30,
                "code": "3.01.03.001",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 31,
                "code": "3.01.03.002",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 32,
                "code": "3.01.03.003",
                "selected": true,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 35,
                "code": "3.01.03.004",
                "selected": false,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 34,
                "code": "3.01.03.005",
                "selected": false,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can you help me to create this recursive function?

```
const countSelectedChildren = (arr) => {

return arr;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to write a recursive function to process the nested arrays.

Comment: Can you write this recursive function?

Comment: I can, but I won't. What's preventing you from writing it, it's not very complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive function for an array and return an object with a counting property and a children array.

```js
const
    addSelected = array => {
        let selectedChildren = 0;
        const
            children = array.map(({ children, ...o }) => {
                if (o.selected) selectedChildren++;
                const temp = addSelected(children);
                selectedChildren += temp.selectedChildren || 0;
                return { ...o, ...temp };
            });

        return children.length
            ? { selectedChildren, children }
            : { children };
    },
    data = [{ id: 1, code: "1", selected: false, children: [{ id: 4, code: "1.01", selected: false, children: [{ id: 5, code: "1.01.001", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 6, code: "1.01.002", selected: false, children: [] }, { id: 20, code: "1.01.003", selected: true, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, code: "2", selected: false, children: [{ id: 7, code: "2.01", selected: false, children: [{ id: 9, code: "2.01.001", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 21, code: "2.01.002", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 22, code: "2.01.003", selected: false, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, code: "3", selected: false, children: [{ id: 8, code: "3.01", selected: false, children: [{ id: 10, code: "3.01.01", name: "Sementes", selected: false, children: [{ id: 11, code: "3.01.01.001", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 23, code: "3.01.01.002", selected: false, children: [] }, { id: 24, code: "3.01.01.003", selected: true, children: [] }] }, { id: 25, code: "3.01.02", selected: false, children: [{ id: 27, code: "3.01.02.001", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 28, code: "3.01.02.002", selected: false, children: [] }, { id: 29, code: "3.01.02.003", selected: false, children: [] }] }, { id: 26, code: "3.01.03", selected: false, children: [{ id: 30, code: "3.01.03.001", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 31, code: "3.01.03.002", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 32, code: "3.01.03.003", selected: true, children: [] }, { id: 35, code: "3.01.03.004", selected: false, children: [] }, { id: 34, code: "3.01.03.005", selected: false, children: [] }] }] }] }],
    result = addSelected(data).children;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple recursion to do this:

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const countSelectedChildren = (xs) => 
  xs .map (({children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = countSelectedChildren (children)) => ({
    ...rest,
    ...(children .length 
       ? {selectedChildren: sum (kids .map (x => (x .selected ? 1 : 0) + (x .selectedChildren || 0)))}
       : {}
    ),
    children: kids,
  }))

const data = [{"id":1,"code":"1","selected":false,"children":[{"id":4,"code":"1.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":5,"code":"1.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":6,"code":"1.01.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":20,"code":"1.01.003","selected":true,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":2,"code":"2","selected":false,"children":[{"id":7,"code":"2.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":9,"code":"2.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":21,"code":"2.01.002","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":22,"code":"2.01.003","selected":false,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":3,"code":"3","selected":false,"children":[{"id":8,"code":"3.01","selected":false,"children":[{"id":10,"code":"3.01.01","name":"Sementes","selected":false,"children":[{"id":11,"code":"3.01.01.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":23,"code":"3.01.01.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":24,"code":"3.01.01.003","selected":true,"children":[]}]},{"id":25,"code":"3.01.02","selected":false,"children":[{"id":27,"code":"3.01.02.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":28,"code":"3.01.02.002","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":29,"code":"3.01.02.003","selected":false,"children":[]}]},{"id":26,"code":"3.01.03","selected":false,"children":[{"id":30,"code":"3.01.03.001","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":31,"code":"3.01.03.002","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":32,"code":"3.01.03.003","selected":true,"children":[]},{"id":35,"code":"3.01.03.004","selected":false,"children":[]},{"id":34,"code":"3.01.03.005","selected":false,"children":[]}]}]}]}];

console .log (countSelectedChildren (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For each element in the input array recur first on any children, then to calculate the `selectedChildren` for our current node we sum up the results from each of our children, adding one for each if it's selected.  Then we simply put back together a new object with `selectedChildren` included if we have actual children, with `children` the result of our recursion, and with the rest of the properties from our element.

While we could inline the one call to the `sum` helper function, it's something we're likely to want fairly often, so it's cleaner to keep it separate.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const countSelectedChildren = (data) => {
   let length = 0;
   for (item of data) {
      item.selected && (length++)
      let child_length = countSelectedChildren(item.children || [])[1];
      length += child_length;
      item.selectedChildren = child_length;
   }
   return [data, length];
}
```

Comment: Note the expected output.  The title is misleading.  The OP want not just to count them but to return a tree with nodes that have a new `selectedChildren` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this

```js
    const countSelectedChildren = (inArr) => {
        
        const outArr = [];
        
        inArr.forEach(row => {
        
          //  simply count all chilren with selected=true
          row.SelectedChildren = row.children.filter(row => row.selected).length;
        
          //  if there are children, call this function on them
          if (row.children.length) {
             row.children = countSelectedChildren(row.children);
          }
          
          outArr.push(row);
        });
        
        return outArr;
        
    }
```

```js
const data = [
  {
"id": 1,
"code": "1",
"selected": false,
"children": [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "1.01",
    "selected": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "code": "1.01.001",
        "selected": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "code": "1.01.002",
        "selected": false,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "code": "1.01.003",
        "selected": true,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
  },
  {
"id": 2,
"code": "2",
"selected": false,
"children": [
  {
    "id": 7,
    "code": "2.01",
    "selected": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "code": "2.01.001",
        "selected": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "code": "2.01.002",
        "selected": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "code": "2.01.003",
        "selected": false,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
  },
  {
"id": 3,
"code": "3",
"selected": false,
"children": [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "code": "3.01",
    "selected": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "code": "3.01.01",
        "name": "Sementes",
        "selected": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 11,
            "code": "3.01.01.001",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 23,
            "code": "3.01.01.002",
            "selected": false,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 24,
            "code": "3.01.01.003",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "code": "3.01.02",
        "selected": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 27,
            "code": "3.01.02.001",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 28,
            "code": "3.01.02.002",
            "selected": false,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 29,
            "code": "3.01.02.003",
            "selected": false,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "code": "3.01.03",
        "selected": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 30,
            "code": "3.01.03.001",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 31,
            "code": "3.01.03.002",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 32,
            "code": "3.01.03.003",
            "selected": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 35,
            "code": "3.01.03.004",
            "selected": false,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 34,
            "code": "3.01.03.005",
            "selected": false,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
  }
];


const countSelectedChildren = (inArr) => {
    
    const outArr = [];
    
    inArr.forEach(row => {
    
      //  simply count all chilren with selected=true
      row.SelectedChildren = row.children.filter(row => row.selected).length;
    
      //  if there are children, call this function on them
      if (row.children.length) {
         row.children = countSelectedChildren(row.children);
      }
      
      outArr.push(row);
    });
    
    return outArr;
    
}

console.log(countSelectedChildren(data))
```

Comment: I think you need to account for the totals you're gathering for the children in the parent as well.  For instance `id: 3` should have a `selectedChildren` length of 6.